# Calculate the total number of entries available along with a conditional query

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate the `count` for a specific condition and I perform:

```
select count(Status) as Status from processing_unit_info where Status = 'Not Registered'
```

Is it possible to also calculate the `count(*)` of all the entries in the table in a single query?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
select count(Status), 
sum(Status = 'Not Registered') as Status 
from processing_unit_info
```

The boolean expression in the `SUM()` function evaluates to true or false, 1 or 0.

Comment: Well, this is a short form, I could also have written `SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Not Registered' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. In the short form, `Status = 'Not Registered'` returns for each row either 0 when this is not true or 1 if it's true. Instead of counting you're summing the result of `Status = 'Not Registered'`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. One possible solution:

```
SELECT 
  count(*) AS total,
  SUM(Status = 'Not Registered') as Status 
FROM 
  processing_unit_info
```